# What is Log Bytes Flushed/sec

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

What exactly does **Log Bytes Flushed/sec** tell me on SQL Server?

I understand it's a metric used in performance tuning/troubleshooting as well as DTU calculations for Azure SQL Databases. I just want to understand what exactly it indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a counter used to measure or investigate I/O performance of a log device. You can use Log Bytes Flushed/sec and Log Flushes/sec to measure the average number of bytes per flush. You can also measure how many milliseconds are spent per log flush. That should tell you the latency of the log.

When log is not showing good performance expect high number of waits of the type WRITELOG.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I could use a bit more clarification please. Is this an indication of how much the database is going to the hard drive? I'm trying to fully understand the meaning of "Log Flush".

Comment: For me is also an indication of how I/O intensive is the workload of a database and determine if I need to scale the tier of the database. Premium tiers are the tiers intended for I/O intensive databases.

Answer (score 1):

From the Red Gate SQL Monitor documentation:

> Explanation: This metric helps to assess utilization and identify
>   trends of the transaction log. A log flush occurs when data is written
>   from the log cache to the physical transaction log file on disk, every
>   time a transaction is committed.

Hope this helps.